# How to identify a result is coming from which index?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know that we can search multiple indexes in elastic search but would I know if a particular search result is belonging to which index?

As per my requirement , I want to provide a global search on different types/indexes but a user should know that the search is coming from which index/context as that will help them to correctly associate the result to the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch adds some fields to the search response. Some od them are `_index` and `_type`. You can use them for your purpose.

So the sample Elasticsearch response looks like below:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 19,
    "max_score": 1.1,
    "hits": Array[10][
      {
        "_index": "first_index_name",
        "_type": "first_type_of_first_index",
        "_id": "doc-id-125125422",
        "_score": 1.1,
        "_source": { /*here is your indexed document*/ }
      },
      {
        "_index": "second_index_name",
        "_type": "first_type_of_second_index",
        "_id": "doc-id-212452314",
        "_score": 0.9,
        "_source": {...}
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```